# RSS feed for a custom page template

Tags: page-template, rss, feed

I would like to know if it is possible to have a custom feed based on a page template and how?

This is my custom query:

```
$my_custom_query = new WP_Query( array('cat' => array (4335, 12488),
    'posts_type' => 'post',
    'showposts' => 35,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'meta_key' => 'views', 
    'orderby'=> 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'desc',
    //'orderby' => 'desc',
    // BOF EXCLUDES POSTS YOUNGER THEN TODAY -30 DAYS *  
    'date_query' => array(
    'column' => 'post_date',
    //'after' => '2010-01-01',
    //'before' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days')) 
    ),
    // EOF EXCLUDES POSTS YOUNGER THEN TODAY -30 DAYS 
    //'offset' => '21',
    'post__not_in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ),
    'meta_query' => array('0' => array('key' => 'videos_na', 'value' => 'true', 'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'),
    array('key' => 'master_id', 'value' => 'true', 'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'),
    array('key' => 'old_id', 'value' => 'true', 'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'),
   )));
```

Comment: Is this page template a custom `WP_Query` or `get_posts` that's re-implementing a post archive so you can put it at another URL or use a page builder? Normal archives can be turned into RSS feeds by adding `/feed` on the end, their URLs can be changed via their post type/taxonomy registrations, and their contents via `pre_get_posts`, otherwise WP will assume that you want an RSS feed of the pages comments

Comment: I've updated my question to expose my custom query. Thanks!

Comment: This was the answer that I needed: [link]https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-custom-rss-feeds-in-wordpress/ Thank you all!